# Can I set one child to be .write: true whilst others are restricted?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object called 'Service'  This can be read by anyone but changes can only be made by the owner.  My firebase rule for this is:-

```
"Service": {
".read": true,
"$uid":  {
    ".write": data.child('owner').val() == auth.uid"
   }
}
```

Service has a child called 'owner' which is == to the users UI when logging in through firebase Auth.

I also have a User object which can make a Service as a favourite.   I'm saving these in the user object as an array of [businessKey:true].

However, I've been asked to also save in the Service object the reverse relation of what users have favourited it.  So an array However as a user isn't always the owner of a service I come into a permissions error.   I'm trying to write rules that allow anyone to write to one child but not the others.

I have tried...

```
"Service": {
".read": true,
"$uid":  {
    ".write": data.child('owner').val() == auth.uid" || data.child('users').val() != root.child('users').val()"
   }
}
```

this is would allow a write if the user was the Service owner or just changing the child 'users'  The effect was that any user was able to write to anything.

I've also tried

```
"Service": {
".read": true,
"$uid":  {
    "$users": {
        ".write" : true,
    },
    ".write": "data.child('owner').val() == auth.uid"
    } 
}
```

thinking this would always allow a write to 'users' and any other child if user was owner.

I'm pretty new to firebase and this rules syntax in general so I'm probably making some glaring error!  If what I want to achieve possible? what have I got wrong?

Comment: If I get you right, you want the owner of a service to have write permission and just a user right? If that is the case this should do the trick for you. "service" : {"$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid || auth.uid === root.child('user').child('$uid').val()"
      }} }